# Double-entry visa procedure for transit in Japan

Tags: visas, transit, japan, multiple-entry

On my trip to Canada which lasts approximately 3 months, I will need to change airport twice in Tokyo (Japan) once for the departure flight and once for the return flight. Because I will be changing airport in both of these flights, a double-entry transit visa is required. What is the difference in the procedure when applying for a double-entry transit visa, compared to that of a single-entry one?

The most helpful source of information I have found so far is: http://www.sg.emb-japan.go.jp/visa_transit.htm

Will the Embassy use my flight itinerary to decide whether a double or single-entry visa is required and issue accordingly? Or is there anything specific I must follow in order to apply for a double-entry transit visa?

Comment: Are you sure you even need a transit visa?  Direct connections via an airport in Japan do not require one.

Comment: I will need to change airport (from Haneda to Narita and vice versa) so I believe a transit visa is required.

Answer (score 1):

Japanese visa applications are processed by actual humans, so you can eg. write both dates of arrival in the form, state purpose as "Transit x 2", and note that you want a double-entry visa in the "Remarks" section of the [application](http://www.sg.emb-japan.go.jp/apply-form-2Apr2013.pdf).

In my experience, Japanese embassies are both very meticulous at following rules *and* helpful at advising applicants how to apply "correctly".  Since every embassy/consulate has its own slightly different procedures, it's usually a good idea to call the embassy or even better go there in person and ask how to apply -- they'll help you out.